# How to Bind to DropDown using Jsonp response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i am using jQuery Ajax to bind data to dropdown.I am using arcgis rest services as source.I am able to get response but not able to bind to dropdown.Can anybody help this done.

```
$.ajax({  
  url: "url",  
  data: { f: "json", where: "1 = 1 ", returnGeometry: false },  
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(response) {     
  console.log( response );

     var len = response.length;

            $("#ddlDistrict > option").remove();
            $('#ddlDistrict').append("<option value='-- Select --'>-- Select --</option>");

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                $('#ddlDistrict').append('<option value="' + response[i].DistrictName + '">' + response[i].DistrictName + '</option>');
            }
  }  
});
```

My console output is

[image]

Comment: response seems to be object but you are tried to iterate as array

Comment: what is going wrong did you check console for any errors?

Comment: No errors.But response.length is undefined.

Comment: @LonelyPlanet response is object but how to bind to dropdown

Comment: What property you are tried to add? features, featureAliases or fields?

Comment: can you paste the exact json response you're getting ?

Comment: @LonelyPlanet features

Comment: @mrid the response is what i put as image

Comment: oh sry...my bad

Comment: on each line you could print the variable & typeof variable so you can debug it easily

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to bind to dropdown"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
success: function(response) {     
      console.log( response, typeof response );
      if(typeof response == 'string') {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
      }
      var len = response.features.length;

        $("#ddlDistrict > option").remove();
        $('#ddlDistrict').append("<option value='-- Select --'>-- Select --</option>");

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(response.features[i]);
            $('#ddlDistrict').append('<option value="' + response.features[i].DistrictName + '">' + response.features[i].DistrictName + '</option>');
        }
```

}

Comment: Hi i am getting undefined.alert(response.features[i].DistrictName);

Comment: It is working for me.I have to make like ....response.features[i].attributes.DistrictName

Answer (score 0):

From the response it seems you want to display `displayFieldName` which has a value of `'DistrictName'`

SO you have to pass the key name

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                $('#ddlDistrict').append('<option value="' + response[i].displayFieldName+ '">' + response[i].displayFieldName+ '</option>');
            }
```

Now from response I see displayFieldName is just a key., where as `features`,`fieldAliases`,`fields` are array,object & array of object again.

I am not sure if you want to target `fields` which have `name` as key and `DistrictName` as value. If it is o then loop condition need to be changes

```
 for (var i = 0; i < response.fields.length; i++) {
  $('#ddlDistrict').append('<option value="' + response.fields[i].displayFieldName+ '">' + response.fields[i].name+ '</option>');
    }
```

Comment: I am getting value to dropdown but values are undefined.

Comment: check the object keys